# Function Reference for custom link in Admin Menu Management Page

Tags: functions, menus, filters, admin-menu

What is the function reference for the text within the URL field in the Admin Menu page?

I have a PHP function that is utilizing `the_content` function reference to look for specific file paths and replace said file path with a custom path.  My goal is to apply this function that is successfully changing paths within my pages/posts to changing the same type of paths when I'm adding custom links in the Admin Menu Management page.

Currently this function that uses `add_filter` and `the_content` function reference is not working for the Admin Menu Management Page.

I create custom menu sets and place them in sidebar's using widgets for easily management "quick links" to other pages and documents.

I've been using the following codex page to find function references: [Function_Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference).

Comment: It'll be better explained if you include sample code, page addresses (`/wp-admin/edit.php`) and snapshots. You can [edit] the Question whenever needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a single filter *just* for a menu item URL, but in `wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php`  there are a few filters:

- `wp_nav_menu_objects` - the menu items before being formatted with HTML
- `wp_nav_menu_items` - a HTML list of the navigation menu items
- `wp_nav_menu` - the completed menu just before output